# Access static resource property from xaml?

Tags: xaml, uwp, staticresource

I'm trying to access a static resource's property:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <FeatureControl
        x:Key="FeatureControl"
        IsSweetFeatureEnabled="True">

    <SweetFeature IsEnabled="{StaticResource FeatureControl.IsSweetFeatureEnabled}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But this gives me a runtime error.

All the posts I've found are dealing with wpf and not uwp.

I know I can pass `FeatureControl` and access the property from within the `SweetFeature` class, but the `SweetFeature` class does not need know about what other features are enabled.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

This is how the property is defined:

```
public class SweetFeature
{
    public bool IsEnabled { private get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ordinarily (in WPF, where I live) I'd say `IsEnabled="{Binding IsSweetFeatureEnabled, Source={StaticResource FeatureControl}}"`, but I think bindings may differ in UWP.

Comment: Actually yeah, I think that might work.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Sadly it doesn't seem to work, I'm still getting a run time error :/

Comment: What runtime error?

Comment: Wow you're responsive!  `Failed to assign to property '<...>.SweetFeature.IsEnabled'`  (Note I've removed the full path.)

Comment: How is `SweetFeature.IsEnabled` defined? It should be a dependency property; can you paste its whole definition into your question? Also can you try sticking this in somewhere, just for testing? `<TextBlock Text="{Binding IsSweetFeatureEnabled, Source={StaticResource FeatureControl}}" />`? I've used `StaticResource` as a Binding source in WPF, and [MSDN says it works in UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart#adding-a-details-view) (ListView.ItemsSource binding -- scroll down a bit)

Comment: Oh, it has to be a dependency property?  That's probably the problem.  `SweetFeature` just defines a standard property (see updated question).

Comment: Yep, a target of a binding must be a dependency property.

Comment: Ah I see.  Thanks for clearing that up!  If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Test it first. There could be something else too.

Comment: To be honest my `SweetFeature` is just a normal class, not a `UIElement`.  So I don't want to add any UI dependencies to it like a dependency property.  I'm simply creating it in xaml.  I'll just set that property programmatically.

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the persistence :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for the binding:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsSweetFeatureEnabled, Source={StaticResource FeatureControl}}"
```